# What about that new feedback mechanism?

Tags: discussion, announcements

Last week, that blog announcement about the sudden change to the question weight, ended with:

> ... along with some new feedback mechanisms we will be announcing next week...

Now, unless I missed the corresponding blog post, or Twitter tweet or MSE question, nothing has happened yet?!

At least for that question-weight announcement, the moderators were briefed about the announcement upfront.

Thus a simple question: does anyone know *when* exactly that new feedback mechanism will be announced, and is free to give at least a bit more detail when exactly to expect an announcement?

(The main reason why I am concerned: lately, when SE Inc. made "late friday" announcement, that lead to plenty of churn... if that is to happen again, it is time to plan for popcorn and pizza, unfortunately)

Comment: Moderators have been briefed on at least a part of the plan and we know the planned date for announcement, but anything more than that is for SE to say.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose is that the new mechanism? A user opens a post and a mod answers in a comment  within 30 minutes based on a briefing in private? If so, do we get free pizza if the response has not arrived within the 30 minutes? ;)

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica hah! If you do get pizza be sure to share with the class eh? I'm hungry.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose there's enough for everyone, but you will have to [get it yourselves](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1661835/142629). The sooner you come the more you get, at least that's my understanding.

Comment: Don't get your hopes up. The official SE feedback mechanism has been `> /dev/null` for a while.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't think I can change anything about what SE Inc. does. I am mainly curious what happens next. And I appreciate to know when to be around for that...

Comment: [Feedback mechanism blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) now live.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thanks for your patience!

The plan when the blog post went out was to release it on the 21st (yesterday). As we were working on it, it became clear that more refinement was needed before releasing so, to avoid putting it out on Friday, we're currently planning to release it on Monday the 25th of November. Hopefully this is early enough before the Thanksgiving break for people in the US.

Comment: Expect lots of thanksgiving ... *I see myself out*...

Comment: Glass half full, Monday is definitely better then friday.

Comment: Thanks. Now let's hope the refinements will result in many more thanks given next week. Just setting expectations, you know.

Comment: The fact this had to be pulled a few days before the release doesn't bode well.  This change must have been discussed extensively at senior executive level. Last minute refinements, in particular just before the weekend, and not to forgot Thanks Giving suggest there were serious flaws in the original implementation. The flaws were at least serious enough to pull the release and the SE development team must be working throughout the weekend to get this delivered.

Comment: @Alex For context, the entire company was at a meetup Sunday-Wednesday. This is more a reflection of needing time for refinement after such a full and exhausting week.

Comment: Catija, I believe your company wants to focus more on enterprise products. Delaying a community release without  any form announcement is fair enough  However, this becomes a different matter if you start having paying customers. Senior SE management should ask themselves if they could have reasonably known this feature couldn't be delivered in time taking into account the entire company was in a four day meet up. Senior management should also ask themselves if they should have announced this delay given it was announced with great fanfare.

Comment: Given the recent trust issues between the community and SE it is also an unfortunate choice to release this change just before ThanksGiving when most of the USA user base will be far less active on this site. Politicians often announce bad news before a major holiday. If SE is not trying to bury bad news, it raises the question why SE is announcing flagship changes at a time when they will be least noticed.

Answer (score 15):

Moderators have been briefed on at least a part of the plan and we know the planned date for announcement, so yes there is still something coming (barring some drastic change).

But anything more than that is for SE to say.

Comment: The answer to that will make much more sense once you know what it is honestly. It's not really possible to give a meaningful answer to that otherwise.

Comment: I really hate this whole "let's keep secrets from the community and not ask for their input!" thing.

Comment: @House-'ReinstateMonica'-man I can understand why you think that might be what's happening here, but I'd encourage you to wait until you hear what it is before making that kind of judgement.

Comment: Thank you. At least for me, it is much easier to be patient having heard your response.

Comment: @House is correct. I don't care what it is. I care that SE tease the users and annoy them by keeping it all super secret. Movie trailer at least gives something, but saying "Hey, you'll get a surprise soon but we will never tell you a bit about it before it's alive" is purely annoying. It feels like the blog author did it on purpose, well aware it will annoy people.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Well, now that I've heard what it is, my judgement remains the same. If anything, I'm even more disappointed.

Comment: @House-'ReinstateMonica'-man That's completely fair. If it helps, moderators were only aware of a small part of what got announced. My only point at the time was that  they weren't really keeping secrets and not asking for feedback and more developing ways to ask the community for feedback and weren't ready to announce them. That being said, what they came out with is at the very least a bit of a mixed bag so disappointment is understandable.

Comment: @House-'ReinstateMonica'-man ... Now, in hindsight, with the announcement being out, I am like: *I also really hate what they proudly announced today*. Alone that part about racial background is so abysmal, I lack words.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica you can also hopefully understand why it was impossible for me to answer the question of feedback sufficiently without understanding what was announced ;)

Comment: I think I understood that already last week. And thanks for notifying me about the announcement.